# Enable minimize of Tawk chat

Tags: javascript, tawk.to

I am using "tawk chat" for my WordPress site.
Chat box is hidden on load and I am using following code to open chat box on click of "open chat". It works perfectly fine but when I minimize it chat box gets disappear. 
I want chat box minimized when user clicks on minimize.

```
<a href="javascript:void(Tawk_API.toggle())">Open Chat</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
var Tawk_API=Tawk_API||{}, Tawk_LoadStart=new Date();
(function(){
var s1=document.createElement("script"),s0=document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
s1.async=true;
s1.src='some URL';
s1.charset='UTF-8';
s1.setAttribute('crossorigin','*');
s0.parentNode.insertBefore(s1,s0);
})();
</script>
```

Comment: Did you check if anything strange is logged in a developer console (like [Chrome's](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/))? If not, can you try that?

Comment: When I clicks on "Open Chat" links or on "Minimize" nothing happens in console.

Comment: Facing the same issue. Events are not getting triggered if you selecting mobile device in developer menu. Works in desktop view.

Comment: The below code is working fine in  java script function <a href="javascript:void(Tawk_API.toggle())">Open Chat</a> when i have deployed in wordpress it is showing the following eror can you help me on this                            Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'viewHandler' of null
at Object.u.toggle.Tawk_API.toggle (default:167)

Answer (score 1):

It is not programitical issue.

1. Go to Tawk.to Admin Panel
2. Go to Admin at the Top of the Dashboard
3. Click on Widget Settings
4. Uncheck "Hide the widget on load"

https://www.tawk.to/knowledgebase/chat-widget/change-how-the-widget-behaves-on-your-site/